# Software that creates conjectures about Euclidean geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-software

Is there a software that creates conjectures about possible theorems in Euclidean geometry?

Something like the following "algorithm":

- Start with three points and add lines, circles, intersections etc. randomly.
- Look for "coincidences", e.g. three lines through a point, three points on a line or circle etc.
- Test the coincidences by repeating the same construction with other, randomly chosen starting points.
- Try to rule out trivial coincidences.
- Present the coincidence as "conjecture"

Comment: You might look at [MMP/Geometer](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-24616-9_4.pdf)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the link. Do you know where you can get the software from? Unfortunately, I did not find out by googling it.

Comment: I suggest you email the authors of that paper at the email addresses given.